# Truffle not able to run two files at the same time

Tags: ganache, testing

I have two files in my test folder, when I run `truffle test` I get results for the first file but by the time it reaches to the second one ganache fails and I get the error below. I have tried placing just one file at a time and running, it runs fine for both of them, but not together.

```
  ProviderError: 
Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > 5777
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" or "--http" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)

      at C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\wrapper.js:73:1
      at C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\wrapper.js:102:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:98:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:349:1)
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:252:47)      at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:9)
      at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Ganache fails and throws this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transactions' of null
    at ProjectsWatcher.handleBlock (C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Local\Programs\Ganache\resources\static\node\truffle-integration\projectsWatcher.js:180:38)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Subscription.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AH30007\AppData\Local\Programs\Ganache\resources\static\node\truffle-integration\projectsWatcher.js:57:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbering the test files as such // 2_Test_First // 3_Test_Second should fix the problem, truffle has trouble discerning which file to run first so by numbering it you are telling it in what order to execute.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, that does not solve the issue, I renamed my files 1_MyToken.test.js and 2_MyTokenSale.test.js but only the first one gets executed and ganache crashes by the time the second one starts being executed. Is this a ganache issue or a truffle error? Any thing else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a call to a contract function without the await and with another call to a function:

```
 //it's gonna crash
 web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:accounts[0], to:accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("2", "ether")});
 let b = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
```

The correct way:

```
await web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:accounts[0], to:accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("2", "ether")});
let b = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
```